# Surrounded Character Method Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, loops, foreach

I'm working on a java method that checks whether a character in an array of characters is surrounded by a character. Ex: abcdc, d is surrounded by c. Ex: abccc, has no letters that are surrounded. Here is what I have so far.

```
public static boolean surroundedCharacter(char[] letters){
    boolean result = false;
    for(char letter : letters)
        if(letters[letter-1] == letters[letter+1]){
            result = true;
        }
    return result;
} }
```

So I basically have a for each loop going through letter in letters and checks whether the letter before the position is equal to letter after the position. If it is, it means that the letter is surrounded and it should change result to true. The junit test says that the if statement is wrong, but I don't know how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Arrays use integers for indexes. With `letters[letter-1]` you are trying to substract a character by 1 which doesn't work

Comment: you should use indexed for loop instead of foreach loop

Comment: Why do you say "abccc" has no surrounded letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an Integer for the index:

```
public static boolean surroundedCharacter(char[] letters){
    boolean result = false;
    for(int i = 1; i < letters.length - 1; i++) {
        // You said that if the string is "abccc", should return false.
        // So, we check if the previous or the next letter is different to 
        //the actual value of i
        if((letters[i-1] == letters[i+1]) && (letters[i-1] != letters[i])) {
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: Also, after result = true, it could be good to add a break statement, because you are only interested to know if exists once. That could be faster and better when you have many elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
    public static boolean surroundedCharacter(char[] letters){
        boolean result = false;
           for( int i=1;i<letters.length-1;i++)
                    if(letters[i-1] == letters[i+1]){
                        result = true;
                    }
}
return result;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use for loop instead of short for. Try this for loop:

```
for(int i = 1; i< letters.length-1; i++){

        if(letters[i-1] == letters[i+1]){
            result = true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A Java foreach is designed to iterate element after element.
In case of need to get two distinct element at each iteration, you should use a classic for using a int value.

Besides, you don't need to have intermediary variable. When the condition is matched you can return true. Otherwise you return false after the loop.

At last, according to your needs :

> Ex: abccc, has no letters that are surrounded.

you should accept the match only if the surrounded char differs from the chars that surround it.

```
public static boolean surroundedCharacter(char[] letters){
    for(int i=1; i<letters.length-1; i++){
        var beforeLetter = letters[i-1];
        var afterLetter = letters[i+1];
        if(beforeLetter == afterLetter && beforeLetter != letters[i]){
            return true;
        }
     }
    return false;
 }
```